# If $A^TA \ge B^TB$ does this imply $AA^T \ge BB^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A^TA \ge B^TB$ does this imply $AA^T \ge BB^T$?
If not, is there a counter example?

Comment: what is the ordering $\ge$ used here? and are the matrices all square?

Comment: A counterexample has already been given, but one can already guess the answer by noting that the two inequalities have different symmetries.  The former inequality is invariant with respect to multiplying A,B on the left by arbitrary orthogonal matrices, whilst the latter is invariant with respect to multiplying A,B on the right by arbitrary orthogonal matrices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$